# MongoDB - Can't push an item to an array inside an object inside an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have this object in MongoDB:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("1"),
  data: {
    city: "ccp",
    universities: [
      {
        _id: "2"
        name: "universityOne"
        students: []
      },
      {
        _id: "3"
        name: "universityTwo",
        students: []
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I need to push a `Student` object inside the `students` array inside the `universityOne` object inside the `universities` array, inside the global object.

I tried documentation and come up with this queries. 
Mongo shell returns `{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 0, "modifiedCount" : 0 }`. And nothing changes.

Here are the queries formatted/unformatted, so you can see them:

```
db.pautas.updateOne({_id: ObjectId("1")}, {$push: {"data.universities.$[id].students": {name: "aStudentName", age: 22}}}, {arrayFilters: [{"id._id": ObjectId("2")}]})
```

db.pautas.updateOne({_id: ObjectId("1")}, {$push: {"data.universities.$[id].students": {name: "aStudentName", age: 22}}}, {arrayFilters: [{"id._id": ObjectId("2")}]})

**This second query is with the name of the university on the mongo `[<identifier>]`. But doesn't work either.**

```
db.pautas.updateOne({_id: ObjectId("1")}, {$push: {"data.universities.$[name].students": {name: "aStudentName", age: 22}}}, {arrayFilters: [{"name.name": "universityOne"}]})
```

db.pautas.updateOne({_id: ObjectId("1")}, {$push: {"data.universities.$[name].students": {name: "aStudentName", age: 22}}}, {arrayFilters: [{"name.name": "universityOne"}]})

Regards.

---

**UPDATE**

Real object:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("5c6aef9bfc1a2693588827d9"),
  datosAcademicos: {
    internados: [
      { 
        _id: ObjectId("5c6bfae98857df9f668ff2eb"),
        pautas: []
      },
      {
        _id: ObjectId("5c6c140f8857df9f668ff2ec"),
        pautas: []
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I need to add a Pauta to the `pautas` array. I've set `pautas` to an array of strings for debugging purpose, so just need to push a "hello world" or whatever string.

I tried this with the answers I've been given:

```
db.pautas.updateOne({"_id":ObjectId("5c6aef9bfc1a2693588827d9"), "datosAcademicos.internados._id": ObjectId("5c6bfae98857df9f668ff2eb")}, { $push: {"datosAcademicos.internados.$.pautas": "hi"}})
```

db.pautas.updateOne({"_id":ObjectId("5c6aef9bfc1a2693588827d9"), "datosAcademicos.internados._id": ObjectId("5c6bfae98857df9f668ff2eb")}, { $push: {"datosAcademicos.internados.$.pautas": "hi"}})

---

Update 2:

Mongo version: v4.0.2
Using Robo 3T.

I created a test database
[image]

And tried this command
[image]

Still not working.

Comment: Is it `_id` or `id` on root level of your document ? If you change the filtering condition from `id` to  `_id` it works

Comment: It was _id, i edited it. Thanks for your answer. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: May be collection name example vs pautas ?

Comment: Jesus, you are right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 3 issues with your statement. First, the root ID field is "id" and you're querying the "_ID".

Second, you should put the match fields altogether. This update works as expected.

Third, you should use "$" to select the nested array position, not "$[id]".

```
db.pautas.updateOne(
{ "id": ObjectId("1"), "data.universities._id": "2"}, 
{$push: 
    {"data.universities.$.students": {name: "aStudentName", age: 22}}
})
```

**Answer to the question UPDATE:**
The update statement worked just fine.

[image: Update statement]
***Update statement***

[image: Record updated successfuly]
***Record after update*** - I ran my update with your data and then the update code you posted, both worked just fine.

Comment: What's the error you're getting when running it? In my tests I removed the ObjectId("1") and used only "1". This was causing some error here.

Comment: No error, same `{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 0, "modifiedCount" : 0 }`. My object is not exactly the same but it's the same structure, I don't know what's wrong. I tried removing every `ObjectId` or only the first or last one, but same thing happened.

Comment: So the problem is in the match sentence. If you post your real object and what you wanna match I can give you a hint.

Comment: I did what you said, please take a look when you have time.

Comment: I updated the answer with some screenshots. The update statement worked just fine here. I am using Robot3T to operate the database. Where are you trying to update those records from? Code? Another interface? What's the Mongo version you're using?

Comment: I made another update with screenshots which show I did exactly the same as you, with different result.

Comment: @Veeram pointed I had a typo in my query. Your example works fine Paulo. I can't understand why my real object doesn't work.

Comment: I just realized that my query had the name of another collection, not the one I was trying to update. Thank you very much for your answers and most of all, your time. This is the correct answer.